# Center Positioning DIV with Background Image using 100% width

Tags: css, css-float

I'm fairly new to CSS and Div positioning and bumped into an issue

I have a status bar at the bottom of an app I'm building -

The status bar is 1600 pixels wide, but because I don't want the browsers to have horizontal scrollbars with anything more than 1000 pixels wide, and because the actual text on the status bar is only in the middle 1000 pixels, I created three images -

Image 1 is the LEFT 200 pixels

Image 2 is the middle 1000 pixels (This is set to an absolute position, stuck to bottom of browser window and works fine)

Image 3 is the RIGHT 200 pixels

What i did was make a 1600 pixel version of the status bar and put it a layer BELOW the 1000 pixel bar and tried to set it up as a background image in a DIV using WIDTH:100%

## footerbr

{

```
background-image:url(images/footerol.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
text-align: center;
padding: 0px;
width: 100%;
height:40px;
position: absolute;
bottom:0px;
z-index: 3; 
vertical-align:bottom;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

}

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here ... Can i use this approach and just allow the browser at let's say 1100 pixels wide to NOT have horizontal scroll bars because I'm using a background image in the DIV ... That being said, I can't seem to center when I have the width:100%

The best approach would be if I could position the left and right element a layer lower than the center 1000 pixel bar and let it slide underneath if the browser window width is reduced (or is small to start out with) .. Basically I just can't have horizontal scroll bars and I don't mind if the left and right pieces of the status bar go under the middle status bar (with a browser window width less than 1600) -

Thanks a lot - I appreciate everyone's help

Comment: it ll be better to help if u added some working eg of ur html in jsfiddle or so..

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to force a footer on the bottom of a page while centering it.  Have a look at 
http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html.  Following the example, you can then place a container within your footer with a specified width and a margin:0 to center:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="header"> </div>
  <div id="main"> </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  <div id="nav2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not having a problem forcing a footer on the bottom of the page ... The problem I'm having is this: The Footer is 1000 pixels wide - That's the useful viewing area for many browsers - I want to put another 200 pixels on the left and right side of the footer that are "optional areas" that won't force the horizontal scroll bars on the browser to show up ... If the browser window isn't 1400 wide (1000 + 200 + 200), the left and right 200 pixel elements (having a lower z-index than the 1000 pixel footer) will just slide under the 1000 pixel footer.

Comment: yeah..i was putting something similar together the other day..came to the conclusion that sticking a footer on bottom w/ position absolute and 100% width wasn't such a hot idea.  The witdh:100% was causing all sorts of havoc as far as cross browser.  I had come to the conclusion that the sticky footer or derivative thereof was the best solution to achieve the effect.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a very simple solution, and also why my simple solution didn't originally work

First, I realized I did not have the

Second, I created a centered background image for the left and right piece past 1000 pixels ...

Third, I used an image in the div to represent the middle 1000 pixels -

This is all I needed to get a centered footer on the bottom with:

1. 1000 pixel center piece
2. 200 pixels on left and 200 pixels on right that would be "fill-in" pieces
3. STicks to bottom of page

## footer

```
{

    background-image:url(images/footerol.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height:40px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    z-index: 2; 
    vertical-align:bottom;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```